# MySQL: Composite Index vs Multiple Indices (Leftmost Index Prefixes)

Tags: mysql, indexing

We have a table that is currently using a composite (i.e. multi-column) index.

Let's say

```
PRIMARY KEY(A, B)
```

Of course we can rapidly search based on A alone (**Leftmost Index Prefix**) and if we want to efficiently search based on B alone, we need to create a separate index for B.

My question is that if I am doing:

```
PRIMARY KEY (B)
```

is there any value in retaining

```
PRIMARY KEY (A,B)
```

**In other words** will there be any advantage retaining

```
PRIMARY KEY (A,B)
```

if I have

```
PRIMARY KEY (A)
```

and

```
PRIMARY KEY (B)
```

Comment: You can't have more than one primary key constraint in a table. The purpose of the primary key is to define the columns you can use to select any row individually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two single-column indexes vs one two-column index in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349817/two-single-column-indexes-vs-one-two-column-index-in-mysql)

Comment: You seem to be confusing primary keys with indexes.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a key point about `PRIMARY KEY` -- it is by definition (at least in MySQL), `UNIQUE`.  And do not have more columns than are needed to make the PK unique.

If `B`, alone`is unique, then have`PRIMARY KEY(B)` *without* any other columns in the PK definition.

If `A` is *also* unique, then do

```
PRIMARY KEY(B),
UNIQUE(A)
```

or swap them.

For a longer discussion of creating indexes, see [*my cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

If it takes *both* columns to be "unique", then you may need

```
PRIMARY KEY(A, B),
INDEX(B)
```

or

```
PRIMARY KEY(B, A),
INDEX(A)
```

Until you have the `SELECTs`, it is hard to know what indexes to create.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple primary keys, so I'm going to assume you're really asking about having an ordinary index.

If you have an index on `(A, B)`, it will be used for queries that use both columns, like:

```
WHERE A = 1 AND B = 2
```

as well as queries that just use `A`:

```
WHERE A = 3
```

But if you have a query that just uses `B`, e.g.

```
WHERE B = 4
```

it will not be able to use the index at all. If you need to optimize these queries, you should also have an index on `B`. So you might have:

```
UNIQUE KEY (A, B)
INDEX (B)
```